# Use sed to discard anything before first backslash (\)

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following string. Note there's a blank space before '\\servername':

```
 \\servername\path\to\user with\spaces\sometimes
```

Or sometimes:

```
SomeInfo: \\servername\path\to\user with\spaces\sometimes
```

I'd like to use `sed` to remove anything before '\\servername'. I can do:

```
sed 's/SomeInfo\: //g'
```

But that doesn't always remove the leading space from the first example for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed 's/^[^\]*//'` seems to do the trick for me.

Depends on having one instance per line.  You didn't specify if that was the case.